# Android - Rearranging elements according to number of child

Tags: android, webrtc, android-relativelayout

I'm building an Video conference application, where I want to rearrange participants' screens to be dynamically rearranged when anyone joins or leaves. e.g. for one participant, his screen will be in center, for two they will be side by side and for three triangular and so on...

I'm using relative layout and adding views in the relative layout programmatically at joining.

what approach should I use for the auto layout alignment with proper aspect ratio. Please help.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to use a custom view to handle your auto alignment functionality.

Answer (score -3):

Because you haven't provided code, I can give you the logic I would use. First, just check how many participants are there.

Next, create mapping  with ints as the tag, and string as the value. Each tag cooresponds to one int, the input:
[image]
(blogs.endjin.com)

Now, have different layouts based on that string value. For example, for the string "side by side" which corresponds to the int 2, you can inflate a different layout, or dynamically change the current one, to have the people side by side. I suggest you use a switch to check this, and have the different cases based off of what the string of the mapping is:

[image]
(www.slideshare.net)

**You want your statement `list-x` in the diagram, to be getting the value of the mapping with the tag of the integer amount of people there are.**

Steps in a more clear, easy to understand way that I have listed out for you:

1. Have a mapping for each amount of people. Amount of people is the
   tag, and the layout is the value.
2. Look for the tag based on amount of people, and check the string
   output, which is the layout. See what the string output is by comparing it with something that can expand the layout

   You need to compare the strings, or the output.
3. Inflate appropriate layout based on string.

Comment: @Kevin Me to,  but I wanted typo make my answer as easy to understand as possible